# Ошибка "OSError" в Python при попытке использовать Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Python 3.8

Возможно, вопрос глупый, просто я совсем новичок в этой теме.

При попытке использовать Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
dr = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    dr = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Возникает только при попытках использовать Selenium. Как это можно исправить?